# Why types cannot be compared straight forward (by "T1 == T2")?

Tags: c#, types, compare, comparison, typeof

I feel, it's a little silly question, but...

I know, that it's the rule, but don't know, why is it.
For 2 types named `T1` & `T2` I can:

```
if (typeof(T1) == typeof(T2))
...
```

, but cannot do it straight forward:

```
if (T1 == T2)
```

Why?

Comment: Theoretically you can. It's just the matter of overloading the operators.

Comment: @m.rogalski: Type names are not a valid expression, as far as I know. So it's more a thing with C#'s grammar than with operators. (Besides, which operators would be there? A type name is not a `System.Type` without `typeof`.)

Comment: @Joey He haven't specified what is `T1` and `T2` in either case. In first case it can be `System.Type` and in other it can be simeple `TModel T1` .. get it?

Comment: @m.rogalski: The question asks about comparing types. They use `T1` and `T2` in `typeof` expressions. I'm fairly certain they tried to imply that `T1` and `T2` are type names, especially considering that comparing `System.Type`s that way already works.

Comment: I imagine that the feature didn't accrue enough points to [climb out of the `-100` hole](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/). There were also probably some issues with syntax and parsing to consider.

Comment: Aside from the _can_ aspect, why would you want this?  This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I've wrote an generic method, where the logic is a slightly different in a pair of places depending on type parameter `T`. I know, I could solve same task using virtual methods (but it leads me to much code duplication) or by 1 base method with diff-s moved into virtual methods (but it leads me to more methods). So, as diff-s are little, I decided to chose an generic method as solution. But I'll appreciate any advise||rebuke.

Comment: IMO doing this is sufficiently unusual (and possibly related to an anti-pattern) to want to draw attention to it by forcing the use of `typeof()`

Answer (score 0):

As [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey) mentioned, type names such as `T1`, `T2` (or `string`, `int`, etc. for that matter) cannot be used as an expression directly due to the syntax of the C# language. Please refer to the following syntax specification:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure

The expression `T1 == T2` is therefore just as invalid (from the compiler's point of view) as is the following:

```
if (string == int) // <-- what does that even mean? Shouldn't that always be false?
    Console.WriteLine("Hooray!");
```

As type names do not have any attached variable types, you must fetch a type representation from the runtime using the `typeof(...)` syntax (which, in fact, returns a value of the type `System.Type`).

One other issue you might run into when allowing `T1 == T2`, is the following:

```
struct t1 { }


void Main<T1, T2>()
{
    Type t1 = typeof(T1); // so far, so good.

    if (t1 == T2) // wait, I'm the compiler and I am confused right now.
                  // Is t1 a type or a variable of the type 'System.Type'?
        Console.WriteLine("Hooray!");
}
```

What should the compiler make of that code snippet? Adding or removing the struct `T1` would break change the function `Main`'s behavior and thus break binary compatibility upon re-compilation.